# How to get/set Menu widget height?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am coding a GUI for my application. I have to respect certain constraints regarding the dimensions of the different elements in my GUI.

When I added a [Menu](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm) widget I guessed I am not able to know which is its height and how to set it.

Is there a method to set/get the Menu widget height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the width and height of a menu. The width and height are a function of what is in the menu. Because tkinter uses native widgets for menus, you have very little control over them.